# Font-awesome animation not working via RDP

Tags: windows, animation, font-awesome, rdp, mstsc

Our users connect to some rdsh Windows servers and are using mstsc to connect on them
Each time they log into the farm, the "Play animations in Windows" is disabled by default.
The user can enable it, but after logoff/login, it's disabled again.
I tried the solution with regedit, to change the value of MinAnimate and/or UserPreferencesMask and/or VisualFXSetting but none of them worked.
I think it's related to mstsc. Cause if I connect via vsphere on the server, the option is enabled, if I try with mstsc it's disabled. But I cannot find a way to keep it enabled

Option in the rdp file.
connection type:i:6
disable menu anims:i:0

Hope someone can help :)

Regards